# Sequelize self-referencing table/model not going recursive

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

Lets suppose I have the following table in my RDBMS called "family":

| id | ancestor_id | family_member |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | great-great-grandfather |
| 2 | 1 | great-grandfather |
| 3 | 2 | grandfather |
| 4 | 3 | father |
| 5 | 4 | son |
| 6 | 5 | grandson |

"id" is the primary key and an auto-increment field, "ancestor_id" is a foreign key witch references it's own table, in other words, "ancestor_id" is a foreign key of "family", target column "id". A table that references itself, right? So far, nothing new. To better illustrate the example, I've added a varchar column, "family_member", it will come in handy latter as one visualizes the intend.

I'm using Sequelize as my ORM solution. I'm not a beginner in it, nor am I a beginner in ORM technology. I was using Hibernate before annotations were a thing, and before JPA started encapsulating it (some 17 years ago).

How should I configure the Model and put my query together, in order for Sequelize to give me the following object, as I query for family member id=6 (the grandson):

```js
{
    id: 6,
    ancestor_id: 5,
    family_member: "grandson"
    ancestor: {
        id: 5,
        ancestor_id: 4,
        family_member: "son"
        ancestor: {
            id: 4,
            ancestor_id: 3,
            family_member: "father"
            ancestor: {
                id: 3,
                ancestor_id: 2,
                family_member: "grandfather"
                ancestor: {
                    id: 2,
                    ancestor_id: 1,
                    family_member: "great-grandfather"
                    ancestor: {
                        id: 1,
                        ancestor_id: null,
                        family_member: "great-great-grandfather"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, Sequelize doesn't go "recursive" on that one, all that I can get is one level deep, if I query for the "grandson" and ask to include the Model itself in the query, it will only return me the "son", and nothing above that.

What I need for this one is for Sequelize to go on until it finds a **null** "ancestor_id", as you can see in my JSON example.

Thanks for the time and patience.

Comment: Did you try `// Fetch all models associated with User and their nested associations (recursively)
User.findAll({ include: { all: true, nested: true }});`

Comment: @Anatoly, just tried. Changed nothing. didn't go beyond the first level as before. back to square one... :(

Comment: I suppose the better way would be to add an additional family id (the same values for all ancestors) and get all needed records by it and then build the tree for family members in memory

Comment: @Anatoly, there's this Sequelize plugin called "sequelize-hierarchy" available, haven't had much luck making it sing yet, but it seems it solves this problem automatically(except for MS SQL Server). Next week I'll try to play with it a little more, lets see if I have some luck. ;-)

Comment: @Anatoly, unfortunately, as I found out last night, "sequelize-hierarchy" will work only with versions 2.x, 3.x, 4.x and 5.x of Sequelize, and I'm running version 6.7.0. There seems to be no support for v6.x nor v7.x available yet. :-(